# ImportError in Cython

Tags: module, cython, importerror

I'm fairly new to cython, so I have a basic question. I'm trying to import a base class from one cython file into another cython file to define a derived class. I have the following code in a single directory called `cythonTest/`:

```
afile.pxd
afile.pyx
bfile.pxd
bfile.pyx
__init__.py
setup.py
```

afile.pxd:

```
cdef class A:
    pass
```

afile.pyx:

```
cdef class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A__init__()")
```

bfile.pxd:

```
from afile cimport A

cdef class B(A):
    pass
```

bfile.pyx:

```
cdef class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B.__init__()"
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [Extension("afile", ["afile.pyx"]), 
              Extension("bfile", ["bfile.pyx"])]

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(extensions))
```

This code seems to compile correctly. Running `import afile` works fine, but running `import bfile` results in the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "bfile.pyx", line 1, in init cythonTest.bfile
    cdef class B(A):
ImportError: No module named cythonTest.afile
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Python 2.7.6 and Cython 0.27.3

Comment: Did you test the *actual* example you posted? The missing module is `cythonTest.afile`  while the setup.py file refers to simply `afile`.

Comment: I wrote the comment above *after* having tested with no problem the samples of the question.

Comment: Can you provide the missing information?

Comment: I checked again (by copy-pasting the code above) and this is the exact code I'm running. I'm compiling the code with the command `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` or `python setup.py install --prefix="~/local"`.

Comment: The error mentions `cythonTest` as a module name and that is found nowhere in either your tree structure or in your setup file.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention that the directory containing all six files is called `cythonTest/`. When I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` I get a new `afile.so` and `bfile.so` in this directory. So it seems I can import the first one fine, but the second one somehow requires `cythonTest.afile` instead of simply `afile`

Comment: You can work by installing the package and import as the full name.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `cythonTest` as a package name (directory containing `__init__.py` used as a package).

The module name needs to be reflected in the extension names for importing to work correctly:

```
extensions = [Extension("cythonTest.afile", ["cythonTest/afile.pyx"]), 
              Extension("cythonTest.bfile", ["cythonTest/bfile.pyx"])]
```

Will also probably need to move the pyx files under the package directory - Cython uses the package name when building the extensions.

Comment: You are right that the directory name in which the six files sit is called `cythonTest/`, however, when I modify the `setup.py` to what you suggest and compile using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, I get a directory `cythonTest/cythonTest/` in which `afile.so` and `bfile.so` sit. If I cd to that directory and run python I can again import `afile` fine but importing `bfile` gives the same error.

Comment: If I run `python setup.py install --prefix="~/local"` it puts the `cythonTest/` folder containing `afile.so` and `bfile.so` in my local python package directory, but somehow I'm still unable to import `cythonTest.afile` or `cythonTest.bfile`. Only cd'ing into the directory and importing `afile` from there works, whereas importing `bfile` gives the same error. Hope this helps!

Comment: `setup.py` cannot be in the package directory. Move it up a level, outside `cythonTest` and use the code above to tell cython to build extensions `afile` and `bfile` under the `cythonTest` package with files under the `cythonTest` dir. The `cimport` in `bfile` also needs to use the fully qualified package name `from cythonTest.afile cimport A`. See [Sharing Declarations Between Cython Modules](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use explicit import. The minus side: you must install the package for it to work.

I have the following structure:

```
.
├── cythonTest
│   ├── afile.pxd
│   ├── afile.pyx
│   ├── bfile.pxd
│   ├── bfile.pyx
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

The files:

cythonTest/afile.pxd

```
cdef class A:
    pass
```

cythonTest/afile.pyx

```
cdef class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A__init__()")
```

cythonTest/bfile.pxd

```
cimport cythonTest.afile

cdef class B(cythonTest.afile.A):
    pass
```

cythonTest/bfile.pyx

```
cimport cythonTest.afile

cdef class B(cythonTest.afile.A):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B.__init__()"
```

The init file is empty, it is only used to define the directory as a module.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [Extension("cythonTest.afile", ["cythonTest/afile.pyx"]), 
              Extension("cythonTest.bfile", ["cythonTest/bfile.pyx"])]

setup(
    packages=['cythonTest'],
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
)
```