# cython import error in same package

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387310/importerror-in-cython) and the answer don't seems to be working. Following is my directory structure.

```
.
├── my_package
│   ├── a.pyx
│   ├── b.pyx
│   ├── b.pxd
│   ├── test.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

a.pyx file

```
cimport my_package.b  as b

class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = b.b()
        self.b.run()
```

b.pyx file

```
cdef class b:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    cpdef run(self):
        print "b is running"
```

b.pxd file

```
cdef class b:
    cpdef run(self)
```

test.py

```
import a

c = a.a()
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

extensions = [
    Extension("my_package.a", ["my_package/a.pyx"]
        ),
    Extension("my_package.b", ["my_package/b.pyx"]
)
]

for e in extensions:
    e.cython_directives = {"embedsignature": True}

setup(
    name = "preprocess",
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
)
```

after running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` there is no compile error. But if I try to run test.py it gives `ImportError: No module named my_package.b`.

Any input will be appreciated.

BTW if we change the first line of a.pyx from `cimport my_package.b  as b` to `import b` it will work.

Answer (score 2):

For `cimport` of a sub-package to work, the package directory needs to contain an `__init__.pxd`.

It is the equivalent of `__init__.py` for `cimport` instead of `import`.

Make directory structure be like this:

```
.
├── my_package
│   ├── a.pyx
│   ├── b.pyx
│   ├── b.pxd
│   ├── test.py
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pxd
└── setup.py
```

Then include pxd files as package data in `setup.py` so that they get installed:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension("my_package.a", ["my_package/a.pyx"]
        ),
    Extension("my_package.b", ["my_package/b.pyx"]
)
]

for e in extensions:
    e.cython_directives = {"embedsignature": True}

package_data = {'my_package': ['*.pxd']}

setup(
    name = "preprocess",
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data=package_data,
)
```

Note - `import numpy` should not be in setup.py as it will make installing package not work unless numpy has already been installed.

Put it in `requirements.txt` to have it installed along with the package.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, I still have some questions.
1. I'm getting `Unknown distribution option: 'include_package_data'` after trying your setup.py. I've tried installing python-distutils-extra(in ubuntu 16.04), but warning didn't go off.
2. I assume __init__.pxd is a empty file just like  __init__.py?
3. Do you have any reference that I can learn from?

Comment: Have updated - need to import from `setuptools` and possibly update setuptools also. `__init__.pxd` should be empty. The [cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io) are pretty good, though do not cover everything. Learning by doing works well.